# Deploying Network; Using Different PC for different user

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapp-development, cpp-ethereum, remix

I am using MIX IDE in Windows.

I have created a new smart contract in Contract.sol, I have 4 Pages of html and there are 4 users.

Each html page is controlled by each user. The pages are also checking, while calling a function, whether it is send by prescribed user.

I want to Work this all pages simultaneously in different systems as different users . How can I do that. And Also I want to control as a new user from raspberry pi 2 b+?

Comment: YOu might want to think about posting some code of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You need http server, i.e. application (may be on NodeJS basis), which works with users accounts and retranslate their qeuries to the Ethereum node (geth process). And, of course you should be connected to the Ethereum network (private or public, depends...) and deploy your contract into the blockchain